# Can't verify fiware-idm user Account

Tags: keystore, fiware

I'm using fiware idm leatest version building from sources

- First I sing up the user [image]

**And this is logs of idm**

```
 skip: /img/keyrock01.png nothing to do                               
    [sass]  skip: /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff nothing to do        
    GET /img/keyrock01.png 304 1.480 ms - -                                      
    GET /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff 304 1.200 ms - -               
    Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `description`, `website`, `imag
    e`, `gravatar`, `email`, `password`, `date_password`, `enabled`, `admin`, `st
    arters_tour_ended`, `extra`, `scope` FROM `user` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`emai
    l` = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1;                                                
    Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `description`, `website`, `imag
    e`, `gravatar`, `email`, `password`, `date_password`, `enabled`, `admin`, `st
    arters_tour_ended`, `extra`, `scope` FROM `user` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`emai
    l` = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1;                                                
    Executing (default): INSERT INTO `user` (`id`,`username`,`image`,`gravatar`,`
    email`,`password`,`date_password`,`enabled`,`admin`,`starters_tour_ended`) VA
    LUES ('aeb5a8fc-3ee7-48af-a0eb-7b9cf849cf8f','Test','default',false,'test@tes
    t.com','e9f7c64ec2895eec281f8fd36e588d1bc762bcca','2018-05-23 10:54:09',false
    ,false,false);                                                               
    Executing (437cc850-daa7-42ad-a04e-12094cad524c): START TRANSACTION;         
    Executing (437cc850-daa7-42ad-a04e-12094cad524c): SELECT `id`, `activation_ke
    y`, `activation_expires`, `reset_key`, `reset_expires`, `verification_key`, `
    verification_expires`, `user_email` FROM `user_registration_profile` AS `User
    _Registration_Profile` WHERE `User_Registration_Profile`.`user_email` = 'test
    @test.com' LIMIT 1;                                                          
    Executing (437cc850-daa7-42ad-a04e-12094cad524c): INSERT INTO `user_registrat
    ion_profile` (`id`,`activation_key`,`activation_expires`,`user_email`) VALUES
     (DEFAULT,'3qfo4sfc358','2018-05-24 10:54:09','test@test.com');              
    Executing (437cc850-daa7-42ad-a04e-12094cad524c): COMMIT;                    
    POST /sign_up/ 200 211.580 ms - 6803                                         
    [sass]  skip: /javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js nothing to do                 
    GET /javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js 304 0.876 ms - -                        
    [sass]  source: /home/ubuntu/fiware-idm/themes/default/jquery.Jcrop.scss     
    [sass]  dest: /home/ubuntu/fiware-idm/public/stylesheets/jquery.Jcrop.css    
    [sass]  read: /home/ubuntu/fiware-idm/themes/default/jquery.Jcrop.scss
```

- I don't receive any confirmation mail so I click on **confirmation not received** 
  and this is the idm logs

  > GET /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff 304 1.080 ms - -
  >   Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `description`,
  >   `website`, `imag e`, `gravatar`, `email`, `password`, `date_password`,
  >   `enabled`, `admin`, `st arters_tour_ended`, `extra`, `scope` FROM
  >   `user` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`emai l` = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1;
  >   Executing (default): UPDATE `user_registration_profile` SET
  >   `activation_key`= 'z0fv4m8l12k',`activation_expires`='2018-05-24
  >   11:07:21' WHERE `user_email` =  'test@test.com'
  >   POST /confirmation 302 78.040 ms - 66
  >   [sass]  skip: /auth/login nothing to do
  >   GET /auth/login 200 4.321 ms - 6786

**For me to be able to verify user**

- I opened mysql database
- SELECT idm database
- Update user table using this 
  `UPDATE user SET enabled = 1 where email= "test@test.com";`After this I'm able to access idm for this user correctly but in my cases I can't do this workaround solution

**So I'm asking if there's away to sent confirmation mail successfully from idm  to user Sig up mail with verification link and after clink the link the Account verified and user can access idm with this account any help**

**Update**
I install smtp-server and configure idm to sto communicate with smtp-server and followed steps to verify account 
- sign up test user 
and this is log of idm

```
GET /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff 304 2.783 ms - -               
[sass]  skip: /img/keyrock01.png nothing to do                               
GET /img/keyrock01.png 304 0.568 ms - -                                      
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `description`, `website`, `imag
e`, `gravatar`, `email`, `password`, `date_password`, `enabled`, `admin`, `st
arters_tour_ended`, `extra`, `scope` FROM `user` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`emai
l` = 'testuser@testuser.com' LIMIT 1;                                        
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `description`, `website`, `imag
e`, `gravatar`, `email`, `password`, `date_password`, `enabled`, `admin`, `st
arters_tour_ended`, `extra`, `scope` FROM `user` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`emai
l` = 'testuser@testuser.com' LIMIT 1;                                        
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `user` (`id`,`username`,`image`,`gravatar`,`
email`,`password`,`date_password`,`enabled`,`admin`,`starters_tour_ended`) VA
LUES ('f11aa78f-2d48-4b36-805c-8ca8383ef44b','Testuser','default',false,'test
user@testuser.com','c178fcf003558346bb951eae536f205ab1420401','2018-05-25 18:
49:42',false,false,false);                                                   
Executing (3b3a82b6-9c0b-44ae-9abe-f3cc4746e06f): START TRANSACTION;         
Executing (3b3a82b6-9c0b-44ae-9abe-f3cc4746e06f): SELECT `id`, `activation_ke
y`, `activation_expires`, `reset_key`, `reset_expires`, `verification_key`, `
verification_expires`, `user_email` FROM `user_registration_profile` AS `User
_Registration_Profile` WHERE `User_Registration_Profile`.`user_email` = 'test
user@testuser.com' LIMIT 1;                                                  
Executing (3b3a82b6-9c0b-44ae-9abe-f3cc4746e06f): INSERT INTO `user_registrat
ion_profile` (`id`,`activation_key`,`activation_expires`,`user_email`) VALUES
 (DEFAULT,'v9hadxsieme','2018-05-26 18:49:42','testuser@testuser.com');      
Executing (3b3a82b6-9c0b-44ae-9abe-f3cc4746e06f): COMMIT;                    
POST /sign_up/ 200 191.699 ms - 6803
```

and this is the logs of smtp-server
[

```
2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] 250-SMTPUTF8                 
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] 250-SIZE 10485760            
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] 250-XCLIENT NAME ADDR PORT PR
OTO HELO LOGIN                                                               
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] 250 XFORWARD NAME ADDR PORT P
ROTO HELO IDENT SOURCE                                                       
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] C: MAIL FROM:<noreply@localho
st>                                                                          
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] S: 250 Accepted              
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] C: RCPT TO:<testuser@testuser
.com>                                                                        
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] S: 250 Accepted              
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] C: DATA                      
[2018-05-25 18:49:43] DEBUG [#7o7cqgw2g77rqfs7] S: 354 End data with <CR><LF>
.<CR><LF>                                                                    
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8                                       
From: noreply@localhost                                                      
To: testuser@testuser.com                                                    
Subject: Welcome to Keyrock                                                  
Message-ID: <c4b64133-9a38-39ab-bc98-0fd5647040b1@localhost>                 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable                                  
Date: Fri, 25 May 2018 18:49:43 +0000                                        
MIME-Version: 1.0                                                            

<!DOCTYPE html>                                    
<html>                                             
<head>                                             
    <meta content=3D"text/html; =                  
charset=3DUTF-8" http-equiv=3D"Content-Type">      
</head>                                            
<body>                                             
    <table style=3D"background-color: #F1F1F2; min-
height: 300px; =                                   
padding-bottom: 40px; border:0; font-family: verdan
a, arial, sans-serif;" =                           
cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"100%">
      <tr>                                         
        <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top">       
          <table =                                 
style=3D"padding: 15px 0px; border:0;" cellpadding=
3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" =                          
width=3D"700">                                     
             <tr style=3D"background-color: #F1F1F2
; =                                                
min-height: 80px; display: block;">                
              <td =                                
style=3D"background-color: white; width:700px;">   
                <img =                             
title=3D'Keyrock' alt=3D'Keyrock' style=3D"height: 
70px;" =                                           
src=3D"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaH
aWlpb0QvLzJRPT0iL
z48L3N2Zz4=3D">                                    
              </td></tr>                           
              <tr style=3D"height: auto; padding: =
20px 15px 10px; color: #666; background-color: #FFF
; font-size: 13px;">                               
                <td>                               
                    <table style=3D"height: auto; =
padding: 20px 15px 10px; color: #666; background-co
lor: #FFF; font-size: =                            
13px;">                                            
                      <tr><td>                     
                                    =              
              <p>Hello Testuser1!</p>              

<p>Welcome to Keyrock! By clicking =               
on the link "I accept" below, you state that you ha
ve read and accepted the=                          
 our Terms and Conditions and the creation of your 
account will be =                                  
confirmed:</p>                                     

<p><a href=3D"http://localhost:3000/activate?=     
activation_key=3Dpr93n16tgk8&amp;email=3Dtestuser1@
testuser1.com" =                                   
target=3D"_blank">I accept</a></p>                 
        =20                                        
                                              </td>
</tr>                                              
                    </table>                       
                </td>                              
              </tr>                                
              <tr>                                 
                <td style=3D"border-top:1px solid =
#48B9C9;"></td>                                    
              </tr>                                
              <tr>                                 
                <td style=3D"border-top: 1px solid 
#FF0; border-bottom: 1px=                          
 solid #193B6B; height: 0px; width: 100%; display:b
lock;"></td>                                       
              </tr>                                
              <tr style=3D"background-color: #FFF;"
>   =                                              
          =20                                      
                <td style=3D"padding:15px 15px 0px;
 display: =                                        
block; padding-bottom: 30px; font-size: 11px;">    
                    2018 =                         
=C2=A9=20                                          
                    <a style=3D"color: #193B6B; tex
t-decoration: =                                    
none;" href=3D"https://github.com/ging" onMouseOver
=3D "this.style.=                                  
cssText=3D 'color: #48B9C9; text-decoration: none;'
" onMouseOut=3D "this.=                            
style.cssText=3D 'color: #193B6B; text-decoration: 
none;'">GING DIT</a>- =                            
Universidad Polit=C3=A9nica de Madrid.             
                </td>                              
              </tr>                                
          </table>                                 
        </td>                                      
      </tr>                                        
  </table>                                         
</body>                                            
</html>
```

[

```
2018-05-25 19:01:58] DEBUG [#bjwvvi7anyru4k3d] C: <19
949 bytes of DATA>                                    
[2018-05-25 19:01:58] DEBUG [#bjwvvi7anyru4k3d] S: 250
 Message queued as abcd                               
ef                                                    
[2018-05-25 19:01:58] INFO  [#bjwvvi7anyru4k3d] Connec
tion closed to [127.0.0                               
.1]
```

I copy the HTML from smtp-server logs and this is the email. Sent to user 
[image]

When I click on **I Accept** I got this error 
[image: n]

So I copied activation link from logs which is " http://localhost:3000/activate?=activation_key=3Dpr93n16tgk8&email=3Dtestuser1@testuser1.com "

I got **invalid csrf token** as response
and this is logs of idm

```
ass]  skip: /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff nothing to do                     
[sass]  skip: /img/keyrock01.png nothing to do                                            
GET /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff 304 1.087 ms - -                            
GET /img/keyrock01.png 304 0.904 ms - -                                                   
[sass]  skip: /activate nothing to do                                                     
Executing (default): SELECT `User_Registration_Profile`.`id`, `User_Regi s t  ra t        
ion_Profile`.`activation_key`, `User_Registration_Profile`.`activation_e x p  ir e        
s`, `User_Registration_Profile`.`reset_key`, `User_Registration_Profile` . `  re s        
et_expires`, `User_Registration_Profile`.`verification_key`, `User_Regis t r  at i        
on_Profile`.`verification_expires`, `User_Registration_Profile`.`user_em a i  l` ,        
 `User`.`id` AS `User.id`, `User`.`username` AS `User.username`, `User`. ` d  es c        
ription` AS `User.description`, `User`.`website` AS `User.website`, `Use r `  .` i        
mage` AS `User.image`, `User`.`gravatar` AS `User.gravatar`, `User`.`ema i l  `  A        
S `User.email`, `User`.`password` AS `User.password`, `User`.`date_passw o r  d`          
AS `User.date_password`, `User`.`enabled` AS `User.enabled`, `User`.`adm i n  `  A        
S `User.admin`, `User`.`starters_tour_ended` AS `User.starters_tour_ende d `  ,  `        
User`.`extra` AS `User.extra`, `User`.`scope` AS `User.scope` FROM `user _ r  eg i        
stration_profile` AS `User_Registration_Profile` LEFT OUTER JOIN `user`  A S   ` U        
ser` ON `User_Registration_Profile`.`user_email` = `User`.`email` WHERE  ` U  se r        
_Registration_Profile`.`user_email` = '3Dtestuser1@testuser1.com' LIMIT  1 ;              
GET /activate?=activation_key=3Dpr93n16tgk8&email=3Dtestuser1@testuser1. c o  m  4        
03 21.857 ms - 18                                                                         
[sass]  skip: /activate nothing to do
```

I change the URL to be

"http://147.27.60.37:3000/activate?=activation_key=3Dpr93n16tgk8&email=testuser1@testuser1.com"

But get **danger: Error activating user**
and this logs of idm after this step

```
Executing (default): SELECT `User_Registration_Profile`.`id`, `User_Registration_Profile`.        
`activation_key`, `User_Registration_Profile`.`activation_expires`, `User_Registration_Pro        
file`.`reset_key`, `User_Registration_Profile`.`reset_expires`, `User_Registration_Profile        
`.`verification_key`, `User_Registration_Profile`.`verification_expires`, `User_Registrati        
on_Profile`.`user_email`, `User`.`id` AS `User.id`, `User`.`username` AS `User.username`,         
`User`.`description` AS `User.description`, `User`.`website` AS `User.website`, `User`.`im        
age` AS `User.image`, `User`.`gravatar` AS `User.gravatar`, `User`.`email` AS `User.email`        
, `User`.`password` AS `User.password`, `User`.`date_password` AS `User.date_password`, `U        
ser`.`enabled` AS `User.enabled`, `User`.`admin` AS `User.admin`, `User`.`starters_tour_en        
ded` AS `User.starters_tour_ended`, `User`.`extra` AS `User.extra`, `User`.`scope` AS `Use        
r.scope` FROM `user_registration_profile` AS `User_Registration_Profile` LEFT OUTER JOIN `        
user` AS `User` ON `User_Registration_Profile`.`user_email` = `User`.`email` WHERE `User_R        
egistration_Profile`.`user_email` = 'testuser1@testuser1.com' LIMIT 1;                            
GET /activate?=activation_key=3Dpr93n16tgk8&email=testuser1@testuser1.com 200 22.253 ms -         
6750
```

**So I very confused why idm dosent verify user account after I got activation link  any suggestions**

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of the IdM (<5.0), unless you set up an email server in order to send the confirmation email, you had to search into the application log for the confirmation link. This was because the IdM was throwing an exception and logging the mail that could not be sent.

In the most recent version of the IdM this may have changed, since they changed the implementation of the component quite a bit. I suggest that you try to downside the severity of the logging from INFO to DEBUG to see if the confirmation email is saved.

On the other hand, if you want to configure an email server, define in [config.js](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/blob/master/config.js.template) the values ​​appropriately to your case.

**Anyway, as far as I know and only for practical purposes, your workaround is perfectly valid!**

Best regards!

Comment: I want to make complete use case so I will install mail server exactly **smtp-server** nodemailer but I want to know after installation process I should edit in idm code or not to integrate idm with  SMTP-server successfully

Comment: You should edit configuration file with the appropiate values to your smtp server, because IdM does not provide an SMTP server. Just look at the example link that I left you in my response (config-template.js)

Comment: I update my question with last state any suggestions